# Pass data to rear view using SWrevealviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, segue, swrevealviewcontroller

I need to pass front ViewController to rear ViewController using SWRevealViewController, but I completely don't know how to do it.

The variable in rear view looks like this:

```
var mainView : ViewController!
```

Any suggestions how to pass into it front ViewController?

Comment: This isn't enough information. What class pushes these view controllers? How does the user navigate back and forth? Why are you passing a view controller to another view controller instead of just sending some specific piece of data?

Comment: Main data in main viewController is an array i need a reference, not a copy of this array so i'm passing whole view, if it's bad solution please tell me how to quickly pass it by reference :)
Rear view works as a side menu, it is launched by tapping menu button, both of those ViewControllers are custom class, main view - ViewController, menu View - MenuViewController.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well it was a good question. Finally after a lot of effort I found a way out for you.

In your viewController.swift file,

```
import UIKit

//Add this line before your class definition
var homeController: ViewController!

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    .......

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        home = self
        .....
    }

}
```

In your rear view controller, you can access the members of the front View Controller.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Sorry I am not at al fluent in Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in prepareForSegue to pass data which works for me

```
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SWReveal"]) {

       SWRevealViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
       [destination loadView];
       UINavigationController *navViewController = (UINavigationController *) [destination rearViewController];

       if ([navViewController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {

          MenuViewController* menuVC = (MenuViewController*)navViewController.topViewController;
          menuVC.title = @"Menu";
        } 
    }
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

SWRevealViewController has two properties that refer to both view controllers: rearViewController and frontViewController. So you should do something like this:

```
    class RearViewController: UIViewController {
    var mainView : ViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad() 
       mainView = self.revealViewController().frontViewController
    }

}
```